# Why is using tail to copy a file so much slower than cp, and using awk twice as fast?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, tail, cp

I'm trying to strip out the header line of a large csv file. But the first methods I tried (using tail and awk) work so slowly compared to copying the entire file!

So, just for fun, let's try a few silly but potentially didactically interesting methods for copying files.

Using cp:

```
$ time cp my_big_file.csv copy_of_my_big_file.csv

real    0m2.208s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m2.171s
```

Using tail:

```
$ time tail -n+1 my_big_file.csv > copy_of_my_big_file.csv

real    0m44.506s
user    0m37.521s
sys     0m3.107s
```

Using awk:

```
$ time awk '{if (NR!=0) {print}}' my_big_file.csv > copy_of_my_big_file.csv

real    0m24.951s
user    0m20.336s
sys     0m2.869s
```

What accounts for such large discrepancies between using tail vs cp vs awk?

Comment: Um, the extra processing required? `cp` just shovels bytes from source to destination, and on your system does that using almost no user mode code. You can't get much more efficient than that.

Comment: Your awk command doesn't make any sense. It's testing that the line number is not 0 inside a block of code that only gets hit for the 1st and subsequent lines. The whole thing could just be `awk '1' file`.

Answer (score 1):

cp is copying fs block by block, without asking itself question. Most thing are happening at kernel level.

tail is reading line by line and does some filtering to recreate a file line by line. Of course, the fs will bufferize in the read and write case, but it is less efficient, cause have to cross several layers (kernel-user space), back and forth